# Generator and/or interpreter of probability models

Tags: probability, modeling

Even simple models in probability theory can be quite confusing (e.g. drawing something with or without returning it, conditional probabilities, one and only one outcome, at least one outcome asoasf...)

In other areas of mathematical modelling (e.g. differential equations) you often have powerful and easy to use modelling tools - I have never seen this for stochastic models.

Do you know of any
(a) generator with which you could in a (e.g.) point-and-click style setup certain probability models and the generator gives you the respective formulas.
(b) an interpreter which gives you possible interpretations of probability formulas in basic (e.g.) urn or coin-toss-terms.

Thank you!

Comment: Graphical models may be similar to what you want: http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/bnintro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend downloading R and then following a good R book on Statistics

R download:

http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/

Here's a reasonable R/Stats book:

[http://www.amazon.com/Introductory-Statistics-R-Peter-Dalgaard/dp/0387954759](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387954759)

I'm sure that other people can supply recommendations on different books.   I assume there's also some "community wiki" on this subject that someone will point out.

Comment: Thank you. This is more like a programming language, I would say. Of course you can *program* probability models with it, but it doesn't seem like an easy to use generator nor interpreter of probability formulas to me.

Comment: @vonjd: R is a programming language, but it makes stats MUCH easier to understand (and ask questions). And, with the right book, learning R means you're learning statistics. Once you get rolling, you can also add Deducer http://www.deducer.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.DeducerManual or Rcmdr http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_Commander ....I honestly don't know of a better/faster way to learn statistics than with R.

Comment: @vonjd: I forgot to mention that R also has plenty of differential equation solvers.  I have used several packages and I can say that it is a lot easier to use R than typical C/Fortran/Basic versions of the same methods.   Here's soda http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/odesolve/html/lsoda.html